# nginx configuration for file hosting server

Tags: file, nginx, centos

Past few days i am experiencing terrible slow http download speed . I have a local file server which is connect with 1gbps utp cable . Server is used for serve static files from storage . I am using nginx as a webserver in my server . But the problem is when i am trying to download files using IDM localy first i get very high speed like 30-70MB/sec but after few secs speed drop into 100-300KB/sec sometimes its goes halt . I have tried lots of way no success . Looking for experts advice .

Cpu configuration

2* E5
16Gb RAM
HDD 4*600 GB (15k SAS under raid 5)

Here is my current nginx conf file

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes auto;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

events {
    worker_connections  9000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
accept_mutex on;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s; 
open_file_cache_valid 30s; 
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors on;


    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush off;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout  30;

# number of requests client can make over keep-alive -- for testing
keepalive_requests 100000;

# allow the server to close connection on non responding client, this will free up memory
reset_timedout_connection on;

# request timed out -- default 60
#client_body_timeout 10;

# if client stop responding, free up memory -- default 60
send_timeout 30;

#server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
    #gzip  on;
# if the request body size is more than the buffer size, then the entire (or partial) request body is written into a temporary file
client_body_buffer_size  128k;

# headerbuffer size for the request header from client, its set for testing purpose
client_header_buffer_size 3m;

# maximum number and size of buffers for large headers to read from client request
large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;

# read timeout for the request body from client, its set for testing purpose
client_body_timeout   3m;

# how long to wait for the client to send a request header, its set for testing purpose
client_header_timeout 3m;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```